# Remove drag on HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

You know how you can click on a HTML element, like mainly images, and drag a "shadow-version" of them on the screen?

Like see the stack overflow logo? If you click and drag it, you can move a dark version of it around the screen.

So my question is, is there any way to remove the dragging of HTML elements, mainly images?

Comment: Which browser?  I cannot drag the logo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a function of the browser. It's a shortcut to make saving images to your local hard drive easier. There are **three ways** to fix or work around this behavior:

- The best way is to replace the image with a `div` that has the same width and height of the image, and set the background-image property to the image you want. Backgrounds aren't draggable, so this will do exactly what you want. For bonus points set the div's style to `display: inline-block;` to make it more closely mimic image behavior.
- The next best thing you can do is make a **transparent** `div` the same size as the image, and position it over the image using absolute positioning and z-index. This is messier to maintain, but it might be easier to implement in your layout.
- The final option sucks. You simply add the following JavaScript to your page somewhere:

  `document.getElementById('my-image').ondragstart = function() { return false; };`

...change 'my-image' to the ID of your image element, and you're done. But this option is a bad idea because it relies on Javascript, which not all browsers will have enabled.

As a footnote, if you're trying to prevent your images being saved - don't bother. It's trivially easy to grab images with or without any amount of clientside protection.

Comment: I could use those methods, thanks man! :D

Comment: That's the idea. ;) I usually go for option 1 when I can, BTW - it works pretty well for rich web applications.

Answer (score 1):

Hypothetically, we're supposed to be able to do this with the CSS [`user-select` property.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/user-select) However, browser support for it is limited and irregular. In my testing, it prevents the *appearance* of selecting text, but does nothing at all to prevent the dragging of images. For now, you'll need to use a workaround, like using background-images, as above.

FWIW, apply the following to remove selectability for all text items in body, or use it selectively with specific selectors to disable select/drag on specific elements:

```
body {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I was so excited when I found out about this and implemented it throughout the app I was developing. I was crushed when it didn't work. +1 for the STANDARDS answer, even though it doesn't work most of the time or in most situations.